# How can this map exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a closed, convex and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $f^{i}: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$ f^{i} (x) = v^{i}x + a^{i},$$ where $v^{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $a^{i} \in \mathbb{R} $

Define $ C = \{x : x \in C, (\forall i = \{1,\dots , n \}, f^{i} \geq 0) \}$

Prove $C$ is closed, convex and bounded.

My question is, how can the function map to $\mathbb{R}$ when it is an addition of an n-dimensional vector and a scalar?

Comment: You have a typo. I suspect the map is defined by $f^i (x)=x^i+a_i $ where $x^i $ is the $i $-th component of $x $ and $a_i $ is a fixed number. This defines $n $ functions, one for each $i=1,\dots,n $.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Is it so then, $x=(x_{1}, x_{2})$, then  $f(x) = x_{1} + a \& x_{2} + a$? So it's a one to $n$ map?

Comment: No, you have a map $f_1 (x)=x_1+a_1$ and another one $f_2 (x)=x_2+a_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I read the question wrongly, and it says $f^{i}(x) = v^{i} x + a^{i}$ . I still don't understand how this can be a mapping into $\mathbb{R}$ . Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Ah, ok, different from my guess. I suspect $v^ix$ denotes the dot product of the two vectors.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo That was my first guess as well, but then this set cannot be bounded, so I am having trouble understanding the question. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: The set is bounded. Each $f^i$ is continuous and has a compact domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that $f^{i}(x) = v^{i}x + a^{i}$ denotes the dot product of a vector $v^{i}$ with the vector $x$, plus a scalar $a^{i}$. That is, $f^{i}$ is an affine functional.

If $v^{i} \neq 0$, the set $C^{i} = \{x \in A: f^{i}(x) \geq 0\}$ is the intersection of $A$ with the closed half-space $\{f^{i} \geq 0\}$, and so $C = \cap_{i} C^{i}$ is the intersection of $A$ with finitely many closed half-spaces. The desired properties of $C$ are immediate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is it correct that if $i=2$, then $f^{2}(x) = v^{2}x + a^{2}$ is equivalent to $v_{1}^{2} x_{1} + \dots + v_{n}^{2} x_{n} + a^{2}$ as in, $v$ and $a$ squared?

Comment: I read the superscripts as _indices_, not as exponents. (This peculiar-looking notation is not uncommon with geometers because of the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation); if you prefer, $f_{2}(x) = v_{2} \cdot x + a_{2}$.)